# Creating button to select armature

Tags: python, scripting

I want to create a ui button in blender, after clicking on it, specified bone controls should get selected in pose mode!
REASON- i am learning animation and some group bone controls needs to be selected repeatedly which is very tedious. That button should select my specified controls!
Please send me code!

Comment: Hi. This isn't a site to ask people to send you code, but to ask and answer specific questions. If you have attempted to code this yourself, please edit the question to show what code you have so far and where you are getting stuck.

Comment: coding seems impossible to me. If anybody have answer of this question in their stack please exchange with me! Please (i know i am dumb fellow!)